# Why do Visual Composer (wpbakery) shortcodes display instead of rendered content on WordPress home page

Tags: wordpress-shortcode, visual-composer, wpbakery

I recently migrated a WordPress site to a new host. After the migration, the home page displays raw Visual Composer shortcodes instead of the rendered content.

For example, the page source contains:

[vc_row][vc_column][vc_text]Homepage content here[/vc_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]

Instead of displaying the actual text and styled content.

**Troubleshooting steps taken:**

-Visual Composer plugin (wpbakery) is installed and activated

-Tried re-saving affected page

-Deactivated and reactivated the plugin

-deactivating plugin causes same problem across all pages

-Page builder editor previews the VC content correctly

**Additional details:**

-Only broken page is one designated as Home Page

-Pages other than home page render VC properly

-Developer that made the site has wpbakery license, I don't but the plugin is loaded and active

-WP admin bar does not appear on home page the way it does on all other pages

Let me know if any other plugin conflicts, theme code, or VC configurations could cause this. I'm stumped why the shortcodes display rather than render only on the home page after migration.

Any help is greatly appreciated!